# Include Floating Action Button library

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am a beginner at Android Studio and using the following library https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button to add Floating Action Button into my project but I don't know how to do that. Please guide me.

Comment: I think this link explains everything. https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button#usage

Comment: Thanks Ahmed.  I added the dependencies as given but in the sample project, I can see a library. How to add that? I copy-pasted too, but still cant manage to do that. I would be great if you can guide me that how to use this library.

Comment: by adding `compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0'` actually you are adding library. so no need of adding library. above link contains complete repo. sample is inside of https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/tree/master/library folder only.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Updated for AndroidX:**

You can use Google's native implementation of FAB: `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton`

Dependency: `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`

---

**Previously (before AndroidX):**

I would suggest using the Design Support Floating Action Button supplied by Google instead as seen here http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html
add this to your gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

and that will include the FloatingActionButton shown here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog

It is generally a better practice to use a supported library than a 3rd party one.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little bit late, but for those who will be looking on how to add Floating Action Button to project that requires [changes in project due to recent migrations to androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) here is the answer. Instead of 
`com.android.support:design` use new `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
}
```

After syncing project just declare FAB in your activity xml file:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add the dependency to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0'
}
```

To see how the buttons are added to your xml layouts, check the sample project.

### For knowledge:

There are two ways you can use library:

1. First way, if the library owner has published library on maven central or any other repository, then we just need to use the given artifact ID in `build.gradle` file. Example: com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0, com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3
2. Another way is to refer the library project in your project, same as what we were doing in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks Paresh. I added the dependencies as given but in the sample project, I can see a library. How to add that? I copy-pasted too, but still cant manage to do that. I would be great if you can guide me that how to use this library.